# How do I have Presto create a Windows service with a specific user name and password?

Tags: deployment, automated-deploy, presto

How do I have Presto create a Windows service with a specific user name and password? I'd post what I tried, but I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are typically three steps to actually creating the service:**

[image]

**First, actually create the service:**

> /c sc create "$(serviceName) $(serviceNameSuffix)" binPath= "$(servicePath)"

[image]

**Second, configure the user and password:**

> /c sc config "$(serviceName) $(serviceNameSuffix)" obj= "$(account)" password= "$(password)" start= auto

[image]

**Third, start the service:**

[image]

As you can see, you're simply using a Window's command prompt to do each of these. Whatever you can do at a command prompt, you can do in Presto.